# Getting a Logger in Symfony WheNot in a Controller

Tags: symfony, logging

I'm working on an EntityRepository class, and I need to dump some data to my log file. I can't use dump() because this isn't going to build a page; it's just going to return some JSON. Eventually.

Normally, in a Controller, I'd use:

```html
$logger = $this->getLogger();
```

But I'm not in a Controller.

Thx for your help.

UPDATE: this is for forensic logging. I'm just using it for debugging purposes. It'll be removed afterwards.

Comment: cite: You should never pass container to the repository, just as you should never let entities handle heavy logic. Repositories have only one purpose - retrieving data from the database. Nothing more (read: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html).

Comment: Logging is and always will be a meta-task. They never do work in service of the application, they do work in service of the developer. You gotta know the rules before you can break them, and unless you're willing to implement something like AOP, then you have to break SRP a little bit in order to add logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into this a bit. My first hunch is "Well, if you could define EntityRepositories as services, then that would make this easy because you could then just inject the logger"

But how do you inject the logger into repositories that doctrine is creating? It turns out you can [specify your own repository factory](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/v1.5.0/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L459)

I'm going to assume all it needs is to implement the `Doctrine\ORM\Repository\RepositoryFactory` interface, but you'll probably want to subclass `Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory`.

You will also need to create your own, base repository class that can hold a logger. Let's start there

**src/AppBundle/Doctrine/EntityRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LoggerAwareEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    protected $logger;

    public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

Now, the factory

**src/AppBundle/Doctrine/LoggerAwareRepositoryFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use AppBundle\Doctrine\LoggerAwareEntityRepository;

class LoggerAwareRepositoryFactory extends DefaultRepositoryFactory
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected function createRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName)
    {
        $repository = parent::createRepository($entityManager, $entityName);

        if ($repository instanceof LoggerAwareEntityRepository) {
            $repository->setLogger($this->logger);
        }

        return $repository;
    }
}
```

Now for the confguration glue to make it all work

**app/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    logger_aware_repository_factory:
        class: AppBundle\Doctrine\LoggerAwareRepositoryFactory
        arguments: ['@logger']
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                repository_factory: "@logger_aware_repository_factory"
```

Lastly, for the actual implementation

**src/AppBundle/Entity/SomeCustomRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Doctrine\LoggerAwareEntityRepository;

class SomeCustomRepository extends LoggerAwareEntityRepository
{
    public function findSomethingCustom()
    {
        // Log something
        $this->logger->log('message');
    }
}
```

> Full disclosure: this is untested code - there might be bugs!

Comment: You can also set the repository factory directly, as of Doctrine 2.4.

$config->setRepositoryFactory(new \AppBundle\Doctrine\LoggerAwareRepositoryFactory($logger));

Comment: Wow all of that for just a logger. Whereas in other frameworks, you just have one exposed across your application. Symfony has made some bizarre choices.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to log the most neat solution would be to create either a doctrine or doctrine entity listener, probably on post load. Inject the logger in the listener.
Once you decide you don't need it, just remove the listener.